# DB migration from WSO2 bps to Camunda

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda, wso2-business-process

We are going to migrate from WSO2 bps version 3.6 to Camunda and we assume that this process should go pretty smoothly but we also have some amount of data stored in WSO2 activity database and we don't wan't to lose it. So I would like to know if anybody has already done such exercise and what might be our steps for such migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I asked the same question on the Camunda forum I received following link -  https://blog.camunda.com/post/2016/10/migrate-from-activiti-to-camunda/ - and it worked for me.